# URI-specific ExceptionMapper in JAX-RS

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, guice

I'm using Jersey, and Guice as my IOC-container. I'd like to know if it is possible to associate an ExceptionMapper with a specific URI. The reason for this is that I want to map the same exception differently based on what URI was visited. For example, suppose I've got the following two exception mappers for my custom exception:

```
public class MyExceptionMapperForFirstURI implements
  ExceptionMapper<MyException> {..return response based on first URI..}

public class MyExceptionMapperForSecondURI implements
  ExceptionMapper<MyException> {..return response based on second URI..}
```

As far as I understand you bind an ExceptionMapper in your ServletModule as follows:

```
public class MyModule extends ServletModule {

    @Override
    public void configureServlets() {
        super.configureServlets();
        bind(MyCustomExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

How would I go about binding `MyExceptionMapperForFirstURI` and `MyExceptionMapperForSecondURI` so that they get associated with the correct URIs. Is this possible, and if possible: is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite late answer ;-) but you can always inject the UriInfo and branch on that. So,

```
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;
```

.....

```
if (matchesA(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath())) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Jip, that is what I did in the end (see my comment to the answer below). I'll mark this as the correct answer to highlight it for others.

Comment: Where did you put this code?  In the `ExceptionMapper`?

Comment: Jip. There is now one `ExceptionMapper` subclass that has access to the abovementioned `UriInfo` that I use to branch on.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how the URI's of your app look like, but if it is possible to split your app into two servlets or filters, then you can do it like that - i.e. have one servlet/filter serve one set of resources and include the first mapper and have the other servlet/filter serve the other set of resources and include the other mapper.

If these are custom exceptions, you can also pass Request as an argument to the exception and have just a single mapper - decide on the response based in the request uri in the mapper.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is that I don't have any servlets as I make use of Jersey to serve my resources. I made use of `UriInfo` (injected with `@Context`) to determine how to build the exact error response in the end.