# Jersey & Guice: How to appoint base path to each ServletModule?

Tags: servlets, jersey, guice, jersey-1.0, guice-servlet

**Question**(**s**)**:**

- How can I define Jersey resources and `ExceptionMapper`s in such a way that they only respond to requests for a certain subset of paths?
- How can I do this without having to decide ahead of time under what base path I would like to host them later?
- How can do this such that I can create a single `war` from composing libraries that each define resources for a particular base path of the web app?

**Background:**
I have a Guice + Jersey v1 webapp, that loads two `ServletModule`s from two different dependencies (`jar`s).
One of them defines resources for rest API endpoints (e.g. `@Path("/purchases")`, `@Path("/payment-methods")`), the other defines resources for a web UI (e.g. `@Path("/")`, `@Path("/products")`).
The `ServletModule` for the former attempts to tie its Jersey resources to the `"/api/"` base path (`serve("/api/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, conf);`), while the latter does the equivalent for the `"/"` basepath (`serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, conf);`)
Both dependencies also define their own Jersey `ExceptionMapper`s; The API's `ExceptionMapper`s respond with a JSON error object, while the web UI's `ExceptionMapper`s generate a HTML response with the help of Freemarker.

However, the result of this combination - where both the API and web UI jars are on the classpath - is that Jersey resources from both dependencies respond to requests that have a path beginning with "/api/" *and* "/".
E.g. the API resource for `/purchases` responds to requests for `http://example.com/api/purchases` *and* `http://example.com/purchases`. Similarly, the web UI resource for `/products` responds to requests for `http://example.com/products` *and* `http://example.com/api/products`.

The fact that Jersey sees two `ExceptionMapper`s for the same exception type (e.g. `NotFoundException`) makes it pick only one, regardless of what the requested path starts with. In my case, the `ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException>` responds to unknown resource requests under both `/api/` and `/`, which is bad for either part of the app.

Comment: Not sure I _completely_ understand the whole situation, but maybe [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7581393/2587435)

Comment: Thanks. [That](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16978646/1296709) will take care of the `ExceptionMapper` issue. It requires that my main/outer `ExceptionMapper` implements the `"/api/"` and `"/"` base-path split as well, but it's good enough :)

Comment: What I would still like to know is how I can prevent a Jersey resource from responding to requests under the `"/"` basepath, when it is bound in a `ServletModule` that's supposed to only configure resources under the `"/api/"` basepath. In the example in the question, the `@Path("/purchases")` resource should only respond to `/api/purchases` requests, but it also responds to `/purchases`  - simply because I have another servlet module that binds more resources and serves them under `"/"`. Let me know if I need to add a more complete code snippet that paints the whole picture.